# Converting subnet mask prefix with C

Tags: c, ip-address, bitwise-operators

I'd like to convert a prefix like /24 to 255.255.255.0 using bitwise operations.

I have tried using unsigned int like so:

```
unsigned int mask = -(1 << 32 - prefix);
```

I am thinking of creating a while loop that adds 1 to the correct place and then decrements to 0.

All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
unsigned long mask = (0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - prefix)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

printf("%lu.%lu.%lu.%lu\n", mask >> 24, (mask >> 16) & 0xFF, (mask >> 8) & 0xFF, mask & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would I format this into 255.255.255.0 for /24 though?

Comment: See the update. You can similarly use `sprintf()` to make a text string.

Comment: If prefix == 0 => result is undefined !!!! so check for zero first

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t mask = (-1) << (32 - prefix);
```

once -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF in 2-complement notation, it does the work

Comment: Shifting negative integers to the left invokes undefined behavior.